# Verbose DNS query to see DNS query order?

Tags: networking, osx, dns, dnsmasq

I typically determine the IP of a host by doing: `$ host -t A example.com`. Is there a more verbose version of this that tells me what's happening in the background, specifically the order of what is queried (/etc/hosts 1st, dns server 2nd)?

As many people can attest to, OS X Lion resolves local `/etc/hosts` entries painfully slowly, and I'd like to see what bottlenecks are causing this. Seems like in theory, `/etc/hosts` should be queried first and name resolution should happen instantaneously for manually entered hosts.

Answer (score 3):

Since Apple has done away with `nsswitch.conf` in Lion, you can view the resolver order with `scutil --dns`.

My guess is you will see "DNS" listed before "local".

It's a bit of a hack, but you can install [DNSMasq](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) on your OS X host and have your system query it for DNS resolution. DNSMasq can read `/etc/hosts` first and serve up the entries it finds there before searching DNS. This restores the proper order to resolution.

The gentleman who wrote [this blog](http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/) has done all of the hard work for you. He describes how to install DNSMasq and configure it on OS X Lion.

Comment: ... Why in the name of Saint Carl the Far-Seeing and Saint Frederick the Compassionate did they dump a perfectly functional resolution mechanic  in exchange for scutil ?

Comment: @Shadur just remember they have their own keyboard layout and have given up on non-glossy displays, that should suffice to understand...

Comment: @Shadur Ask Different. http://apple.stackexchange.com/  :)

Answer (score 0):

I find `dig` particularly useful in that realm. The default output is verbose and shows what is being done (what gets sent and what is received.)

There is an example:

```
alex$ dig m2osw.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> m2osw.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52965
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;m2osw.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
m2osw.com.      85160   IN  A   138.197.205.139

;; Query time: 18 msec
;; SERVER: 75.75.75.75#53(75.75.75.75)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 19 18:02:58 PDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54

alex$
```